# Will deleting question affect my account?

Tags: discussion, support, moderation

I want to know if I delete my own question will affect the **reputation system** or trigger any **question asking ban**?

I am asking this before deleting because I have already been banned on other StackExchange website and don't want to be blocked here.

Comment: Deleting a question doesn't prevent a ban

Comment: No, I mean when I delete a question, will it take me near to banning my question asking privilege?

Comment: More info please!! Deleting your question will trigger a reputation recalc. And deleting a single question shouldn't trigger any ban either.

Comment: See this - http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133500/177471

Answer (score 6):

> I delete my own question will affect the reputation system

Deleting a post schedules a reputation recalc to correct the reputation. So if your post had a positive score, you'll lose the rep and a negatively scored post will restore the rep.

> delete my own question will  trigger any question asking ban?

Deleting a question doesn't trigger the question ban, neither does it absolve you from the ban.

Quoting [the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/133693)

> An automatic filter is in place to ban questions and/or answers from
> IP addresses or accounts with a history of extremely poor posts. To
> avoid bypassing the filter its internal rules are a secret, but it is
> partly based on downvotes cast by other members of the communities.
>
> #### Are deleted posts taken into account too?
>
> Yes, deleted questions (if less than 30 days old) and deleted answers
> count towards an automatic ban.

So a poor post followed by deletion doesn't make the system ignore your previous post. If you *don't* want to be banned, you should think about what you write and write clearly.

Consequently, deleting a question doesn't trigger the ban either.